# Can I use PrivateObject class or Reflection to access a field in a private class?

Tags: c#, reflection

If i have a private class

```
Class A
{
    public static string foo;
}
```

Can i use reflection to access that static field? Assuming of course i cannot change the code...

The problem i have is that the Class is defined in a different Namespace than i am in.

lets say I am in the Test namespace, and i have a reference to a DLL with the FOO namespace.

```
   namespace FOO
   {
     Class A
     {
         public static string bar;
     }
   }
```

I want to access the *bar* field in the class A from namespace TEST.

Comment: Yes you can, but be very careful doing this - even if it's a CLR class, it might change in a servicepack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You'll need to get the `Type` - how you do that will depend on the exact nature of your app; [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) would be one option, for example. After that, you get the `FieldInfo` with `Type.GetField` and then ask the field for its value, using `null` as the target as it's a static field.

Comment: Thanks! i ended up using the Assembly approach:

Answer (score 2):

What finally worked for me was the Assembly approach:

```
assembly = typeof(Class B).Assembly; //Class B is in the same namespace as A
Type type = assembly.GetType("FOO.A");
string val = (string) type.GetField("bar",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is intentionally verbose so you'll get what is happening step by step. It checks all the fields in type A and looks for one named "foo".

EDIT: it works for A in a different namespace too.

```
namespace DifferentNamespace
{
    class A
    {
        public static string foo = "hello";
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Type type = typeof(DifferentNamespace.A);
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            string name = field.Name;
            object temp = field.GetValue(null); // Get value
                                                // since the field is static 
                                                // the argument is ignored
                                                // so we can as well pass a null                
            if (name == "foo") // See if it is named "foo"
            {
                string value = temp as string;
                Console.Write("string {0} = {1}", name, value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me using another namespace.. when compiling, i get the "DifferentNamespace.A is inaccesible due to it's protection level" error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
object value = typeof (Program).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(x => x.Name == "foo").FirstOrDefault()
    .GetValue(null);
```